# Unix equivalent of '@ECHO ON'

Tags: shell, unix

Need to confirm if there is a UNIX equivalent command for '`@ECHO ON`' in DOS.

I am required to echo each command and then its O/P. I can do it by adding an echo statement for each command that I execute from my script. But I don't want to do it with a echo statement for each command in my script. Curious to know if there is a command that does the same functionality as '`@ECHO ON`' in DOS.

Comment: You can use `set -x` at the top of your Unix shell script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To turn on tracing

```
set -x
```

To turn off tracing

```
set +x
```